# How to express variables efficiently for SED?

Tags: bash, sed

There are many ways to express arithmetic things: new and old ways. 
However, I would like to write this line efficiently and well

```
sed -n '$START,$ENDp;$ENDq' < data.tex
```

which output

```
sed: 1: "$START,$ENDp;$ENDq": invalid command code S
```

### Total Code

```
#!/bin/bash
function getStart {
        local START="$(awk '/begin\{document\}/{ print NR; exit }' data.tex)"
        echo $START
}

function getEnd {
        local END="$(awk '/end\{document\}/{ print NR; exit }' data.tex)"
        echo $END
}

START=$(getStart)
(( START-- ))
echo $START

END=$(getEnd)
(( END++ ))
echo $END

sed -n '$START,$ENDp;$ENDq' < data.tex
```

where the SED is getting the linenumbers from local variables of functions.
How can you express the first line by expressing the variables efficiently for the SED?

Comment: @don_crissti No, just me keeping up my Unix skills by processing my notes, but hitting my head sometimes. Feel free to say a better way about processing the thing once.

Comment: `sed '/begin{document}/,/end{document}/!d;/end{document}/q' data.tex`

Comment: Yours is superior! I thought the thing absolutely too complicated. Thank you!

Comment: I want open boundaries. I opened a new thread about it here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229060/16920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded in single quotes. Use double quotes:

```
sed -n "$START,${END}p;${END}q" < data.tex
```

Also, since you want the value of `END` followed by the character `p`, and not the value of `ENDp`, you need to indicate where the name of the variable ends. You can use the `${END}` syntax, which makes it explicit where the variable name ends.

Note that if $START or $END are not numbers but regular expressions, you might need to escape some characters.