# How to SED with open boundaries?

Tags: sed

I was thinking too complicated the slicing in the [How to express variables efficiently for SED?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229054/16920)
I want to include (a,b), not [a,b] like this *don_crissti*'s command:

```
sed '/begin{document}/,/end{document}/!d;/end{document}/q' data.tex
```

So I do not want to include `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in the output. 
How can you having an open interval in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do so. I suppose that is more undestandable (choice interval and remove which you don't like to include:

```
sed '/begin{document}/,/end{document}/!d;/begin{document}/d;/end{document}/d' data.tex
```

or with [don-crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti)'s [receipt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/show-only-text-between-2-matching-pattern):

```
sed '/begin{document}/,/end{document}/!d;//d' data.tex
```

Other way is start printing after begin in loop till the finish line:

```
sed -n '/begin{document}/{:;n;/end{document}/!{p;b;};}' data.tex
```

Comment: @Masi Check modified. What kind of explanation you need more?

Comment: How do you explain this `{:;n;/end{document}/!{p;b;};}`? It is rather cryptic to me.

Comment: Yes, your commands work as expected in GNU SED. Good!

Comment: @Masi `:` — mark; `n` — get next line ; `/end{document}/!` — line, which **not** (`!`) consist pattern; `p` — print ; `b` — return to mark

Comment: Why do you need the return mark `b`?